# Subset rows based on increments which got changed - R

Tags: r, subset

I want to subset some rows in a data frame/table which depends on some starting points and got incremented by certain formula.
For exemplification, I have created the data below:

```
  Day =  seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 15, by = "days")              
  set.seed(123)
  df1 <- data.frame( rowid =  c(1:30),
               Category = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", 
                      "ID1","ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2",  "ID3", "ID3","ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3"),
               Day =  rep(Day, 2),
               Var = sample(1:30, 30, TRUE) )
  df1
```

I have a defined starting position, e.g start = 2. It represents the starting position for each ID relative to its category.
For instance, ID1 start ar rowid=2, ID2 start at rowid=16 and ID3 starts at rowid= 26.

I want to subset for each ID - starting at its starting position - all rows which got incremented as follow: increment[i]= increment[i-1] + constant.
Constant is a constanta number, let's say 3.

The output should be like:

```
  rowid     Category        Day       Var
    2       ID1         2000-01-02     19
    5       ID1         2000-01-05     10
    8       ID1         2000-01-08     11
    11      ID1         2000-01-11     14
    13      ID1         2000-01-13     25
    16      ID2         2000-01-01      5
    19      ID2         2000-01-04     25
    22      ID2         2000-01-07      9     
    26      ID3         2000-01-11     26
    29      ID3         2000-01-14      9
```

Any help on this?
Thank you

Comment: Im having a bit trouble in inderstanding your logic? Care to elaborate your increment function, please? To me it seems like you just want every 3rd `row` from the starting point, yes?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I want every nth row (3rd) from the starting point for each ID

Comment: Shouldn't be `rowid == 14` instead of `rowid == 13` in the result?

Comment: Right, sorry and thank you

Comment: @gogo88 - if one of the answers below worked for you, can you accept it so that it's removed from the unanswered list? Good to keep that list as short as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence and select rows with `slice`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(Category) %>% slice(seq(2, n(), 3)) %>% ungroup

#   rowid Category Day          Var
#   <int> <chr>    <date>     <int>
# 1     2 ID1      2000-01-02    19
# 2     5 ID1      2000-01-05    10
# 3     8 ID1      2000-01-08    11
# 4    11 ID1      2000-01-11    14
# 5    14 ID1      2000-01-14    26
# 6    16 ID2      2000-01-01     5
# 7    19 ID2      2000-01-04    25
# 8    22 ID2      2000-01-07     9
# 9    26 ID3      2000-01-11    26
#10    29 ID3      2000-01-14     9
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

start <- 2
increment <- 3

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  filter((row_number() - start) %% increment == 0) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Basically, this code applies the filter to individual Categories and keeps row designated by the increment and start values provided.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
> subset(df1, !!ave(rowid, Category, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) %in% seq(2, length(x), 3)))
   rowid Category        Day Var
2      2      ID1 2000-01-02  19
5      5      ID1 2000-01-05  10
8      8      ID1 2000-01-08  11
11    11      ID1 2000-01-11  14
14    14      ID1 2000-01-14  26
16    16      ID2 2000-01-01   5
19    19      ID2 2000-01-04  25
22    22      ID2 2000-01-07   9
26    26      ID3 2000-01-11  26
29    29      ID3 2000-01-14   9
```

Answer (score 1):

A way could be to use `ave` where I update a `logical` vector which has only `FALSE` and set the position got with `seq` to `TRUE` by *Category* and use the result to subset *df1*.

```
start <- 2
constant <- 3

df1[ave(logical(nrow(df1)), df1$Category, FUN=function(i) 
  `[<-`(i,seq(start, length(i), constant), TRUE)),]
   rowid Category        Day Var
#2      2      ID1 2000-01-02  19
#5      5      ID1 2000-01-05  10
#8      8      ID1 2000-01-08  11
#11    11      ID1 2000-01-11  14
#14    14      ID1 2000-01-14  26
#16    16      ID2 2000-01-01   5
#19    19      ID2 2000-01-04  25
#22    22      ID2 2000-01-07   9
#26    26      ID3 2000-01-11  26
#29    29      ID3 2000-01-14   9
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Category) %>%
     filter(rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), length.out = n()))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Category [3]
   rowid Category Day          Var
   <int> <chr>    <date>     <int>
 1     2 ID1      2000-01-02    19
 2     5 ID1      2000-01-05    10
 3     8 ID1      2000-01-08    11
 4    11 ID1      2000-01-11    14
 5    14 ID1      2000-01-14    26
 6    16 ID2      2000-01-01     5
 7    19 ID2      2000-01-04    25
 8    22 ID2      2000-01-07     9
 9    26 ID3      2000-01-11    26
10    29 ID3      2000-01-14     9
```